# Where are my errors in reasoning? (Recursion C)

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, pass-by-reference

So i want to do a recursive function which multiply a number with 2. It works with call-by-value. My problem is that i cant use call-by-reference. I mean it will compile but i'll get a warning. Atleast i dont know how to do it properly, maybe you can help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int *rekursion(int *n){
    if((*n) > 1000){
       return 0;
    }
    printf("%d\t",(*n));
    return rekursion((*n)*2);
}


int main() {

int n  = 10;

rekursion(&(n));

printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Error: 
test16.c:15:22: warning: passing argument 1 of 'rekursion' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

   15 | return rekursion((*n)*2);
      |                  ~~~~^~
      |                      |
      |                      int

test16.c:9:21: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
    9 | int *rekursion(int *n){
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: Well, in your main function you're passing a pointer, and in the function you're passing an integer. And why do you want to pass it by reference anyway?

Comment: What is `return rekursion((*n)*2);` supposed to do? `(*n)*2` dereferences the pointer and multiplies by 2. But this is not a pointer that is expected by `rekursion()` function. Do you want to double `*n` before calling the functiton?

Comment: Thats indeed true, i saw it now. I just wanted to try it with reference, so is there even a way to do it with reference?

Comment: So i want to double the value of n, just that i can do a printf in my main function after the break.

Comment: Look at my answer maybe you will get what i mean

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C, only pass by value and pass by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Does not compile, because the `recursion` function expects a pointer to an memory address, and you are passing a value.

Look at this: `int *rekursion(int *n)` Expects a pointer(memory address).
and then, this one: `return rekursion((*n)*2);` This is not a pointer, its a rvalue.

```
int *rekursion(int *n){
 
   if((*n) > 1000){
      return 0;
   }
   printf("%d\t",(*n));

   // assign the value that the pointer n points multiplied by two, and then. 
   *n = (*n) * 2;
   return rekursion(n);
}
```

You does not need to return a pointer.
You can simply write this:

```
void rekursion(int *n){

   if((*n) > 1000){
      return ;
   }
   printf("%d\t",(*n));
   *n = (*n) * 2;
   rekursion(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed my programm and I got it, thanks for your inspiration!

```
int rekursion(int *n){

if((*n) > 1000){
   return 0;
}
printf("%d\t",(*n));
*n = *n * 2;

return rekursion(n);
}


int main(){

int n  = 10;

rekursion(&(n));

printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to a pointer. You can simply write this:

```
return rekursion(n);
```

Full program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *rekursion(int *n) {
    if(*n > 1000) {
        return 0;
    }
    *n *= 2;
    printf("%d\t",*n);
    return rekursion(n);
}


int main() {
    int n  = 10;
    rekursion(&n);

    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the second `(` and `)`.